# MySQL 'OR' Statment - Determine Which Part Returns the Row

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL SELECT statement (along with PHP):

```
SELECT *
FROM EVENTS
WHERE (
 time1
 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00"
 AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
)
OR (
 time2
   BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00"
   AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
)
```

The above query returns the following row:

```
    id   |        time1        |       time2        |
   -------------------------------------------------
    26     2013-04-22 19:45:00  2013-04-26 12:25:00
```

So, obviously, `time1` is what returned the row.

**My question is:** When I am iterating through the rows with my SELECT statement above, how can I determine whether it was time1 or time2 that 'triggered' (for lack of a better term) the row to be returned?

Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't think this is possible as far as I know - why don't you just prepare 2 separate queries (one for time1 and the other for time2) so you'll always know which one 'triggered' the return?

Comment: @Saturnix: I definitely considered this, but I wanted to see if it was possible to do within the SELECT statement first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
        IF(time1 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00", 
          'Time1', 'Time2')  Result
FROM    EVENTS
WHERE   time1 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00" OR
        time2 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
```

The additional column called `Result` just tests what column did the condition returns true. If for instance both returns true, only `time1` will be on the `result` column.

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE
            WHEN time1 BETWEEN '2013-04-22 19:30:00' AND '2013-04-22 19:50:00' AND 
                 time2 BETWEEN '2013-04-22 19:30:00' AND '2013-04-22 19:50:00'
            THEN 'Time1 and Time2'
            WHEN time1 BETWEEN '2013-04-22 19:30:00' AND '2013-04-22 19:50:00' 
            THEN 'Time1'
            ELSE 'Time2'
        END Result
FROM    EVENTS
WHERE   time1 BETWEEN '2013-04-22 19:30:00' AND '2013-04-22 19:50:00' OR
        time2 BETWEEN '2013-04-22 19:30:00' AND '2013-04-22 19:50:00'
```

Comment: do you want to return `time1 and time2` if both conditions are true?

Comment: Yes, I probably would want to return time1 and time1 if both are true.

Comment: Yup, this was it.  I would not have been able to come up with statement on my own.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

JW's answer is spot on, however I would create a flag for both "triggers" (as they could both trigger):

```
SELECT
    *,
    IF(time1 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"), 'yes', 'no') AS in_time1,
    IF(time2 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"), 'yes', 'no') AS in_time2
FROM EVENTS
WHERE
    time1 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
    OR time2 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00" AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but somthing like this:

```
SELECT *,  IF(time1
 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00"
 AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00",1,0) as fromtime1
FROM EVENTS
WHERE (
 time1
 BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00"
 AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
)
OR (
 time2
   BETWEEN "2013-04-22 19:30:00"
   AND "2013-04-22 19:50:00"
)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if